# remove unwanted argument

Tags: java

I'm writing and java program which uses command line to pass some arguments to the `main()` method. Then I'll use a method I've written to test if it's true or false. If it's false I'll remove that arguments and keep all the true argument so all the true arguments can be use in the subsequent method.

This is what I have now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String str : args) {
        str.istrue
    }
}
```

So how do I let every true arguments to be use later and remove the false arguments?

Comment: You cannot do str.istrue but you can do if (Boolean.valueOf(str))

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean like...

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> goodArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String arg : args)
       if (isGoodArgs(arg))
           goodArgs.add(arg);
    // use goodArgs or convert this back to a String[] with toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String result ="";
for (String str : args) {
    if(str.equals("true"))
        result = result + str;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List list=new ArrayList();
for (String str : args) {
    if(isValidArgument(str))
        list.add(str);
  }

boolean isValidArgument(String str)
{
  //logic to check valid argument like
return str.equalsIgnorecase("true");
}
```

Comment: close but i think you took the is True too literally. i think it meant check it/ varify/ pass it thru a function to see if passes. not the best english but that fits better :)